# Array.GetValue() returns new instance of an struct object

Tags: c#, arrays, structure

I have an unknown array of struct type. When I'm trying to get some index I get a NEW instance of this object:

```
var inst = ((SomeStruct)((Array)arrOfSomeStruct).GetValue(0));
```

Now **inst** is a different instance from **arrOfSomeStruct[0]** .

What is the **best** or the **fastest** way to get the original instance of the array item, and NOT by using **[ ]** operators?

Comment: What are you trying to do that requires the source `struct`?

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve? As soon as you __assign__ a struct value to a variable, as in `var inst2 = inst1;`, the value is copied, so a new instance is created. As soon as you __unbox__ a struct value that has been residing in an `object` box, as in `var inst = (SomeStruct)obj;`, a new value/instance is created. As soon as you implicitly __box__ a struct value, as in `public object GetValue() { /* ... */ return someStruct /* boxing! */; }`, a new instance is created in a new box. Is your struct mutable or immutable since you care about all this?

Comment: `var inst = orig_arr.GetValue(0);

inst.x = 5;

// Now orig_arr.x != inst.x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is default behavior of interaction with a struct. It is copied, not referenced. This is the same for every exchange with a struct, not just your `GetValue` method (also `this[index]` for example).

As [Jeppe Stig Nielsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1336654/jeppe-stig-nielsen) commented:

> ... for an array of value types, `.GetValue(0)` returns a reference to a *boxed copy* of the struct value. On the other hand `[0]` is the original struct value. If you assign to a variable, *then* a copy is made, as in `var valueCopy = arr[0];`. However, that is mostly relevant for mutable value types. If the struct has a member that mutates the struct value, then `arr[0].MutateValue();` will mutate the original. Of course `valueCopy.MutateValue();` will change the copy.

The best option you have is to make the struct an object, ie. move to a class.

In some **extreme** cases, the use of unsafe code is a last resort:

```
unsafe
{
    Point p = new Point(1, 2);
    Point*[] points = new Point*[] { &p };

    Point* p2 = points[0];

    p2->X = 2; // this changes both p and p2
}
```

Comment: To clarify, for an array of value types, `.GetValue(0)` returns a reference to a _boxed copy_ of the struct value. On the other hand `[0]` is the original struct value. If you assign to a variable, _then_ a copy is made, as in `var valueCopy = arr[0];`. However, that is mostly relevant for mutable value types. If the struct has a member that mutates the struct value, then `arr[0].MutateValue();` will mutate the original. Of course `valueCopy.MutateValue();` will change the copy.

Answer (score 4):

You can't get the original if it is a `value type`. Every `Value Type` will be copied if it is returned from the method or passed into the method.

To work as you want you must use a `reference type(class)`